# XSD String pattern which inlcude email with Latin characters

Tags: xml, xsd, pattern-matching, xsd-validation, xml-validation

```
<xsd:element name="MigrCustContactEmail" type="StringX50Email" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>


<xsd:simpleType name="StringX50Email">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
            <xsd:pattern value="[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~.\-]+[@][A-Za-z0-9.\-]+"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

It is working fine for normal email but when it comes string like this in XML "groupesÖtoureiffel.paris@maill.com"

It give error :
cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'groupes╓toureiffel.paris@mail.com' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern `'[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+[@][A-Za-z0-9.-]+' for type 'StringX50Email'`

Can anyone help me with what to change in the pattern?

Comment: Why only Latin? If you're going to extend beyond ASCII, then surely you need to extend beyond Latin as well? Have you actually done any research - google for "email RFC Regex" (and ignore any results earlier than 2010 or so) and you will quickly discover this subject is a minefield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```php
<xsd:pattern value="[\p{L}0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[\p{L}0-9.-]+"/>
```

The `\p{L}` construct matches any Unicode letters.

*Details*:

- `` [\p{L}0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+ ``  - one or more Unicode letters, ASCII digits, `!`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `&`, `'`, `*`, `+`, `/`, `=`, `?`, `^`, `_`, `` ` ``, `{`, `|`, `}`, `~`, `.` or `-`
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[\p{L}0-9.-]+` - one or more Unicode letters, ASCII digits, `.` or `-`.